# Is it possible to vectorize the scipy Dirichlet PDF function?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization

I know that some `scipy.stats` pdf functions are vectorized out of the box, as stated in the [manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats.html#common-methods).

My problem is that I've tried  utilizing this vectorization with Dirichlet's pdf, [`scipy.stats.dirchlet.pdf(x, alpha)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.dirichlet.html#scipy.stats.dirichlet) hopping that I could calculate an array of values for multiple `x`'s for the same `alpha` parameter. Something that could get the same results as

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st

alpha = [1,10,1]
list_of_xs = np.random.dirichlet(alpha,10**6)

values = np.array([st.dirichlet.pdf(x, alpha) for x in list_of_xs)])
```

Being honest I don't really need to vectorize the pdf function, but doing it with a `for` loop takes so long that I hopped that the vectorization could accelerate the code.

### Things that I've tried

- Passing `alpha` as an array of shape `(10**6, 3)` stacking them with `np.vstack([alpha] * 10**6)`

This does not work because Scipy throws the following error:

```
ValueError: Parameter vector 'a' must be one dimensional, but a.shape = (1000000, 3).
```

which (in my understanding) shows that the function is not vectorized out of the box, at least in the way I expected.

- Vectorizing the funciton with `f = np.vectorize(st.dirichlet.pdf)` and then calling the new function f with the stacked alpha `f(x, alpha)`

This did not work because Scipy throws the following error:

```
ValueError: Parameter vector 'a' must be one dimensional, but a.shape = ().
```

Which I think happened either because I've misused the `np.vectorize()` function or the pdf function cannot be vectorized in this way.

So, if it's possible to vectorize this function, how could I do this? Is the work for it worth it? I mean, in my simple understanding, vectorization almost always helps speeding up this kind of code, but I'm not sure if it is the case here.

Comment: Why not pass in an alpha of shape `(N * 3,)` and reshape to `(N, 3)`

Comment: @MadPhysicist I did not quite understand... Passing an `alpha` of shape `(N * 3,)` throws the error `Vector 'x' must have either the same number of entries as, or one entry fewer than, parameter vector 'a'` and reshaping it to `(N, 3)` is the same as stacking them with the `np.vstack()`, isn't it? Also, isn't important to keep the dimension of `alpha` for a Dirichlet pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the exact result you want by simply transposing the first argument:

```
st.dirichlet.pdf(list_of_xs.T, alpha)
```

The documentation for [`dirichlet`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.dirichlet.html) hints that this might be possible, but the links are a mess, so it's never stated explicitly:

> Note that the dirichlet interface is somewhat inconsistent. The array returned by the rvs function is transposed with respect to the format expected by the `pdf` and `logpdf`.

On a related note, I've submitted [PR #14190](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/14190) to scipy to see if the links on the docs can be fixed.